# How do I map checkboxes onto MVC model members?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, iis, model

I have an MVC view

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" MasterPageFile="PathToMaster" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<ModelData>" %>
```

and I have a form with HTML markup for a set of checkboxes:

```
<label for="MyCheckbox">Your choice</label>
<input type="checkbox" id="Option1" class="checkbox" name="MyCheckbox" value="Option one" />
<label for="Option1">Option one</label><br />
<input type="checkbox" id="Option2" class="checkbox" name="MyCheckbox" value="Option two" />
<label for="Option2">Option two</label><br />
```

and I have a controller-action pair

```
class MyController : Controller {
    [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
    public ActionResult RequestStuff( ModelData data )
    {
    }
}
```

and that action is invoked when the form is submitted.

How do I map the checkboxes onto members of `ModelData` (and what members I have to add to `ModelData`) so that when the form is submitted `data` stores information on which checkboxes are checked?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

OK, this one will be for MVC3, but - save for syntax changes - should work in MVC2 too. The approach is essentially the same.

First of all, you should prepare an appropriate (view)model

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    [DisplayName("Option 1")]
    public bool Option1 { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Option 2")]
    public bool Option2 { get; set; }
}
```

Then you pass this model to the view you're showing (controller):

```
public ActionResult EditMyForm()
{
    var viewModel = new MyViewModel()
    return View(viewModel);
}
```

with the form:

```
@model MyViewModel
@using( Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.Label("Your choice")

    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Option1) // here the 'LabelFor' will show you the name you set with DisplayName attribute
    @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.Option1)

    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Option2)
    @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.Option2)
    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
    </p>
}
```

Now here the HTML helpers (all the `CheckBoxFor`, `LabelFor`, `EditorFor` etc) allow to bind the data to the model properties.

Now mind you, an `EditorFor` when the property is of type `bool` will give you the check-box in the view, too. :)

And then, when you submit to the controller, it will auto-bind the values:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult EditMyForm(MyViewModel viewModel)
{
    //And here the view model's items will be set to true/false, depending what you checked.
}
```

Comment: Mentioning EditorFor is a good point. EditorFor is useful almost always. Depending the data type it creates text input, textarea, checkbox and so on.

Answer (score 3):

First you define `SelectList` for Options. This will be used just to render checkboxes

```
    public IList<SelectListItem> OptionsSelectList { get; set; }
```

Than, you define model that will hold value of single chosen option after post

```
public class ChooseOptionViewModel
{
    public int OptionIdentifier { get; set; } //name or id
    public bool HasBeenChosen { get; set; } //this is mapped to checkbox
}
```

Then IList of those options in `ModelData`

```
public IList<ChooseOptionViewModel> Options { get; set; }
```

And finally, the view

```
    @for (int i = 0; i < Model.OptionsSelectList.Count(); i++)
    {
        <tr>
            <td class="hidden">
                @Html.Hidden("Options[" + i + "].OptionIdentifier", Model.OptionsSelectList[i].Value)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Model.OptionsSelectList[i].Text
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.CheckBox("Options[" + i + "].HasBeenChosen", Model.Options != null && Model.Options.Any(x => x.OptionIdentifier.ToString().Equals(Model.OptionsSelectList[i].Value) && x.HasBeenChosen))
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
```

After post, you just inspect `Options.Where(x => x.HasBeenChosen)`

This is full-functional, and it will allow you to redisplay view when validation errors occur, etc. This seems a bit complicated, but I haven't come up with any better solution than this.