# MVC Checkbox value not working

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, checkbox

Hi i have a check box for a checklist program that i am making, its type is bool? so that i can pass a null value if the answer is not applicable (they should leave the yes and no blank), otherwise they should tick yes or no..my problem now is how can i save the answer to my answer property.

View:

```
   YES
              @Html.CheckBox("chkYes", Model.questionnaires[itemindex].Answer.HasValue  ? bool.Parse(Model.questionnaires[itemindex].Answer.ToString()):false)
   NO
               @Html.CheckBox("chkNo", Model.questionnaires[itemindex].Answer.HasValue ? !bool.Parse(Model.questionnaires[itemindex].Answer.ToString())  : false)
```

Model:

```
public bool? Answer { get; set; }
```

Changed my view from checkbox to radiobutton:

```
  YES
                  @Html.RadioButtonFor(modelItem => modelItem.questionnaires[itemindex].Answer,true, new { id = "rbYes"}) 
                 NO
                    @Html.RadioButtonFor(modelItem => modelItem.questionnaires[itemindex].Answer,false, new { id = "rbNo"}) 
                 Not Applicable
                    @Html.RadioButtonFor(modelItem => modelItem.questionnaires[itemindex].Answer,null, new { id = "rbNotApp"})
```

my problem now is how to pass a null value when not applicable?

Comment: Model.questionnaires[itemindex].Answer = true. I think you are missing ==.

Comment: yes i forgot adding another = since im just typing outside the code editor, i already changed it to bool.parse..will update my code in a while

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You 2 checkboxes (and the associated hidden inputs) will be rendered as

```
<input type="checkbox" name="chkYes" ...>
<input type="hidden" name="chkYes" ...>
<input type="checkbox" name="chkNo" ...>
<input type="hidden" name="chkNo" ...>
```

which will post back to properties named `chkYes` and `chkNo` (which don't exist) but you property name is `Answer`.  You can use `@Html.EditorFor(m => m.questionnaires[itemindex].Answer)` which will render a dropdown with 3 values (True/False/Not Set) or you could use 3 radio button to indicate the state.

Note also you cannot use a `checkbox` for a `nullable bool`. A checkbox has 2 states only (checked = true or unchecked = false) whereas a `nullable bool` has 3 states (true, false and null). In addition a checkbox does not post back a value if its unchecked

If you use radio buttons, then

```
YES
@Html.RadioButtonFor(modelItem => modelItem.questionnaires[itemindex].Answer, true, new { id = "rbYes"}) 
NO
@Html.RadioButtonFor(modelItem => modelItem.questionnaires[itemindex].Answer, false, new { id = "rbNo"}) 
Not Applicable
@Html.RadioButtonFor(modelItem  => modelItem.questionnaires[itemindex].Answer, string.Empty, Model.questionnaires[itemindex].Answer.HasValue ? (object)new { id = "rbNotApp" } : (object)new { id = "rbNotApp", @checked = "checked" })
```

Comment: i cant seem to understand, i need to post the answer back, my problem is that it now saves null to everything despite the answer being yes or no

Comment: You are not rendering any inputs with `name="questionnaires[0].Answer"` so nothing is posted back to the property `Answer` so of course its null. The name of your inputs must match the name of your property (in this case because you have a collection, it must also include the indexer)

Comment: hi stephen i changed my checkbox to radiobutton now, please see my edited code. my question now is how to pass a null value if not applicable? thanks

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the HTML is rendered with two input for same properties like #Stephen Muecke said in his answer. Because both of the input has the same name, the form post doesn't take either one. I didn't find the hidden input very useful so i removed it on page load using JS like below.

```
 @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.IsRFD, new { @class = "checkbox" })
 @Html.LabelFor(model => model.IsRFD)
```

JS:

```
 $('input[name="IsRFD"][type="hidden"').remove();
```

Now it is working perfectly with no problem so far...

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand one thing. If the answer is just 'Yes' or 'No', why use checkbox? Shouldn't Radio buttons be used for the purpose? You can implement in the simpler way as:

```
@Html.RadioButtonFor(m=>m.Answer , new{ Name="Answer"}) Yes
@Html.RadioButtonFor(m=>m.Answer , new{ Name="Answer"}) No
```

If you still want to go with your method you can directly bind it to model I think:

```
YES  @Html.CheckBoxFor(m=>m.Answer)
NO @Html.CheckBoxFor(m=>m.Answer)
```

Make model field as:

```
public bool Answer { get; set; }
```

Handle null request in controller after postback..

Comment: first it was radiobutton, but later i had to change it since some questions is not applicable. thats why my answer is nullable to handle this.

Comment: @anonymous1110: Try handling null requests after postback in controller.

Comment: @Saket, How can you handle a null? The value is either `true` or `false`. There will be nothing in the postback to indicate a `null` value!

Answer (score 0):

[Why doesn't my checkbox map to an MVC model member?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10651030/why-doesnt-my-checkbox-map-to-an-mvc-model-member)

Here you have an example of how you must map the checkbox to your mvc model. Checkboxes are trashy, but there is always a workaround.

Model :

```
namespace TestAppMVC2.Models
{
    public class MyModel
    {
       public bool Option1 { get; set; }
    }
}
```

View :

```
<fieldset>
    <legend>Fields</legend>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Option1)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
         @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.Option1)
         @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Option1)
    </div>

    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Save" />
    </p>
</fieldset>
```

Comment: can this handle if the user doesnt want to answer? i need to pass it as nullable if not applicable

Comment: You can place 2 checkboxes for Yes and No, but you will need 2 properties in the model to accomplish this functionality. If the user didn't check yes or no, there is your nullable option.

Comment: @anonymous1110 Make the `bool Option1` as nullable `Nullable<bool> Option1` and remove the line `@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Option1)` from razor.

Comment: Or like @GauravSinghJantwal said (reliable shortcut), but the user can be surprised by your approach.

Answer (score 0):

In MVC, we can not change de model value because MVC generates a hidden input of your checkbox, but we can obtain the value by jquery and change the model.

With this example:

@Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.Option1)

In js use this (in onchange event or whatever you need):

var checked = $("#Option1").is(':checked');
$("#Option1").val(checked);